# Updated MiKTeX (2024-03-12), lua debug function not working

Tags: luatex, miktex

The MWE below works with Overleaf (TeXLive 2023), but does not with MiKTeX as `debug.getinfo` is `nil` -- perhaps this library is not loaded properly in the new update? I have relayed the issue to MiKTeX's github repo, but am curious if anyone knows how this could be temporarily fixed? Another standard library, `math` for example, stil works. The error occurs when using `texlua` to run a lua script as well.

Overleaf prints the name of the function as expected, but MiKTeX throws an error `Error:attempt to call a nil value (field 'getinfo')`.

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1459

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Hello world.
\begin{luacode*}
  function testfunction()
     return debug.getinfo(1, "fn").name
  end
  tex.sprint(testfunction())
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Overleaf: you can check there, `level` is not defined. I think you are reading e.g. https://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.html and missing that you need to supply the level as a number.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to update my example... Please see the revision. Overlead prints the name of the function as expected, but MiKTeX throws an error `Error:attempt to call a nil value (field 'getinfo')`

Comment: with luatex 1.18 you need to use the `--luadebug` option to enable the library.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you! Is there a possibility of enabling the library at run time instead of using the command line option?